# Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-toolbar, material-components-android

I try to use the toolbar in my app and I get this message: "Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar".
i glad if someone will find my problem (using the latest version of the android studio)

XML:

```
  <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00008577"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/main"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>
```

JAVA:

```
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViews();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }

    private void findViews() {
        drawer_layout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        nav_view = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    }
```

STYLE:
 `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">`

Exception received

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.or.ourshoppinglist/com.or.ourshoppinglist.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

Comment: What is your exception?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.or.ourshoppinglist/com.or.ourshoppinglist.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class <unknown>

Comment: I think you need to provide all your xml file, it is related to it at line 28

Comment: I added a comment with them

Comment: I think your style cause the problem for inflating the toolbar, you have to use `Theme.AppCompat` one

Comment: I got the same error. Toolbar fails if any of its parameters fail. It didn't specify which one. I had to delete the parameters and start adding one by one until I found which one was having problems. In my case, for example, it was that the "drawable" resource was in the path but not on the disk. I did not go further into the cause, just copy the resource to the corresponding folder and problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Hi noa shen and welcome to Stackoverflow.

Firstly, there can be an issue with your import for Toolbar. Since androix version came out now you got two versions of Toolbar:

```
androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```

and

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

So first check your imports in your JAVA.class and see if you imported the right version which would be:

```
androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```

Besides that, why is your toolbar width equals to 0?

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Also to use toolbar you need to paste this in your build Gradle file in dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
```

If this doesn't solve anything please provide your whole XML, JAVA.class, and full stack trace of your exception.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  "import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;" this is my import. I added the implementation and still, it didn't work.

Comment: @noashen please edit your question and add your whole XML file and JAVA file. Also giving us your whole exception would be great.

Comment: I added a comment with them

Answer (score 1):

In `build.gradle (module app)` file,  implementation of The upgraded version : `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'` caused me the error. When I used `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'` , The error has gone.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by changing `android:background` to `app:srcCompat` when I am using
`?android:attr`.

For example:

from this xml code

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00008577"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/main"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>
```

change to

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="#00008577"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/main"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

added my whole XML

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00008577"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/main"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</ScrollView>


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
package com.or.ourshoppinglist;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout drawer_layout;
    private NavigationView nav_view;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViews();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer_layout,toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
    }

    private void findViews() {
        drawer_layout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        nav_view = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to remove line in XML under Toolbar "android:minHeight="?actionBarTheme"" and just add under android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"